# How can I cut a single HTML tag using VIM?

Tags: html, vim

When editing HTML I often use VIM commands such as **diw** to cut a word, **dit** to cut whats inside of two tags, and **dat** to cut everything around two HTML tags.

What is the correct way to cut just a single HTML tag?

For example, I would like to only cut the first `<div>` from the following line:

```
<div> something </div>
```

**diw** will only cut the first character "<" , **dit** will cut "something", and **dat** will cut the whole line

How do I just obtain the first `<div>` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+delete+html+tag

Comment: Thanks for this. I spent ages searching via Google with no luck. Next time I'll use the stackoverflow search feature instead.